# Convert $x^2 + y^2 = 2ax$ to a polar equation, where $a > 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, polar-coordinates

This isn't homework *exactly*, but rather I'm teaching a class on precalculus and I'm a little stuck on a question from the textbook.

> Convert $x^2 + y^2 = 2ax$ to a polar equation, where $a>0$.

This is incredibly simple to do: note that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, and $x = r\cos\theta$. Then the equation is simply: $$r^2 = 2ar\cos\theta.$$ However, the answer in the back of the textbook is $$r = 2a\cos\theta.$$

**Here's my question**: Why can we divide by $r$? What happens if $r=0$? Not for every $\theta$ will $r=0$, so why is it valid to simply divide by it?

$r$ is the equation of a circle with radius $a$ whose center lies on the $x$-axis, and graphically the pole $r=0$ exists on the graph. So what gives?

Comment: Maybe... $r^2=2a r\cos(\theta) \ to \ r(r-2a\cos(\theta))=0 \ to \ r=0\vee r=2a\cos(\theta)$ with $\cos(\theta)\ge 0$.

Comment: Note that if $r=0$ then we get the point $(0,0)$, the same that we get when $\cos(\theta)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

$r=0$ covers only one point, namely the pole.  Can $r=0$ satisfy the new equation?  Yes, if $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.  Therefore, you haven't changed the set of points that satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I admit they do not give enough detail.
$$ (x-a)^2 + y^2 = a^2.  $$
With $a > 0,$ this is tangent to the vertical axis at the origin. The polar expression $r = 2 a \cos \theta$ covers the circle twice, once with $ r$ positive while $\; - \pi/2 < \theta < \pi / 2,$ then again with $r$ negative while, say, $\;  \pi/2 < \theta < 3 \pi / 2.$ At the odd multiples of $\pi/2,$ we get the origin because $r=0.$

I guess you need to decide whether your students will be able to deal with negative $r.$

[image]

Comment: Well, I mean how do I go from $r^2 = 2ar\cos\theta$ to $r = 2a\cos\theta$? The obvious answer would be to divide by $r$, but I'm just concerned for when $r=0$: how do I know I'm allowed to do that? You claim that $r$ is positive for $\theta\in\left[-{\pi\over2},{\pi\over2}\right]$, but if $\theta = -{\pi\over2}$ or $\theta = {\pi\over2}$, then $\cos\theta = 0$, which $0$ is neither positive nor negative.

Comment: @Decaf-Math I had originally strict inequality signs, I put them back now. I agree that "dividing by $r$" is not an adequate description. However, the curve $r = 2a \cos \theta$  actually does cover the entire circle.